# UIImagePickerController picture size issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I've tried to find proper answer but no success.

I have code as below which works fine (I can get picture from library) but image size I got always is <= device width.
To be precisely - image in device gallery is for example 4k and picked image is "UIImage: 0x7ce6a5e0> size {640, 480} orientation 0 scale 1.000000" for iPhone 4s

When I'm changing "self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true" to "false" I got no image (nil).

My goal is to pick from library original size image.

Can someone help me ?

```
@IBAction func newButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let SelectImage = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TakePhoto", comment: "comment"), style: .Default){ (action) in

        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.noCamera()
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(SelectImage)

    let chooseImage = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("PhotoLibrary", comment: "comment"), style: .Default){ (action) in

        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addAction(chooseImage)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "comment"), style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)


    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        print(selectedImage)
        takenPhoto = cropToSquare(image: selectedImage)
        Util.addRecord(takenPhoto)
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("saveToSettings", sender: self)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Look at the other keys besides `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`. See the one for getting the "Original" image?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed obvious solution.